# I am trying to do a Order by after a Limit Query

Tags: mysql, limit

So this is my First Question here, so please forgive me if something is wrong.

I am trying to do Order by a limit query.

So there is a Customers table of 90 records.

I want Limit 3 records query to be done first and then sort this query records by a column called ContactName.

I think it would be a nested. The nested works fine in SQL server, but don't know how to do in MySQL.

Limit Query:

```
Select * from customers limit 3;
```

Order by after limit Query ( My guess, but this doesn't works):

```
Select * from (Select * from customers limit 3) Order by ContactName;
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: `SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY ContactName LIMIT 3`?

Comment: "this doesn't works" isn't a question. What is the error? Does it return non-expected result?

Comment: After posting answer I found @Justinas already answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

you just need this

```
Select * from customers Order by ContactName limit 3;
```

Comment: this command gives another set of records.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a subquery in a `FROM` or `JOIN` clause, you're required to give it an alias.

```
Select * 
from (Select * from customers limit 3) AS x
Order by ContactName;
```

Note that using `LIMIT 3` without `ORDER BY` in the subquery doesn't really make much sense -- you don't know how it's going to choose the 3 customers to return. It would make more sense if you were choosing the 3 newest customers and then ordering them by name:

```
Select * 
from (
    Select *
    from customers 
    order by registration_date DESC
    limit 3) AS x
Order by ContactName;
```

Comment: The First command is giving error: Error in SQL:
Table 'northwind.customers' doesn't exist

Comment: That's the table name you specified in the question.

Comment: yes, I am trying in W3schools.com, but still it is giving me the same error.

Comment: The First command finally worked. Big Thanks for the explanation. you rock Sir :-)